# How can I inject virtual DOM as string to dynamically render customized react components

Tags: javascript, dom, virtual, inject

As what the subject said ,I need to inject virtual DOM as a string to dynamically render customized react components. I will use bellow code to help explain my intention.
I have defined bellow two components:

```
class Component_A extends React.Component {
render() {
    return ( 
       <div > 
           <h1>This is Component_A </h1>
           {this.props.children} 
       </div>
    );
}

class Component_B extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return ( 
            <div >
              <h1> This is Component_B </h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I also got a string variable which define the components combination.

```
var testStr = "<Component_A><Component_B><Component_B></Component_A>".
```

Then how can I inject this string to React to render the component ? Similar to implement bellow intention:

```
function showComp() {
ReactDOM.render( 
   <div >
    {testStr}
   </div>,
   document.getElementById( 'dialog' )
);
```

}

The reason why string variable is that, I have many other customized components like Component_C , Component_D and so on. And I also have many other string variables obtain from remote server which are used to define different combination of above components.

So I wanna dynamically render the components out through injecting the string to React Render.
This is different with

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

because it is html string inject and the standard html tag can be recognized. But for my question, the tags are customized.

Is it possible or not ?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?